# Is Riven on a spherical planet?

Tags: video-games, myst

In the game Riven, on the island with the large gold dome, one can find a telescope which points into the ground. If opened, one can see stars, which suggests that perhaps a lot of the ground beneath is either gone or never existed

- Before the fissure appeared, was Riven on a spherical planet?
- Are there other islands or continents beyond the horizon, or is Riven limited to what is reachable within the game?

Comment: If it has a horizon, then it's a spherical planet (or some kind of convex curve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That telescope points into the Star Fissure, it's unclear what the star fissure is, other than:

> Things that fall into it end up on Earth.  It can be traversed by people (though perhaps not safely). The star fissure isn't exactly an indication of parts of the age going missing, but more likely an expanding inter-dimensional rift of some sort.

It's generally accepted that an age is a complete world or planet itself.  The books mention that sometimes an age is destroyed when for example the world has fallen into a star (as mentioned in the Book of T'ana).  There are counters to this rule however such as Catherine's "impossible" age.  Or the prison age written for Ghen.

Comment: Actually, the Age is a univers in itself, and the planet is just one planet.  According to the Wiki, the D'ni found it easy to concentrate on one area, like an island or a small area and apparently often didn't worry about what was even on the other side of the planet, much less on other planets in an age.

Comment: @TangoOversway, Indeed, as we know that it's possible to link to different places in the same age, we have no way of knowing if different ages exist in the same universe or not.  The D'ni attitude of the natives of the ages they link to can pretty well be summed up with the fact that most D'ni didn't even know there was anyone living on the surface of Earth.

Comment: There's an exception about linking to places in the same age.  While you can do it from outside an age, it's not possible to link to a place within an age from within that same age.

Comment: The games contradict that, Uru specifically has instances of linking books taking you to a different area within the same age.

Comment: Interesting.  Than the wiki is not up to date!

Comment: @Brandorf don't tell me you're implying uru has anything to actually do with the established mythos.  it broke so many conventions that the series had FIRMLY established, wrapped with a terrible control scheme and extremely lackluster gameplay.  some of the environments were cool (D'ni especially) but the game was in all other regards about as far removed from the series as myst 5 was (another game with a tenuous at best hold on the mythos)

Comment: Just as how Myst IV changed and expanded what a 'prison age' was (directly contradicting what Atrus's journal says in Riven), so too can the later games, expand what is capable with linking.  Especially Uru and Myst 5, as those were made by Cyan, whereas 3 and 4 were not.

Answer (score 5):

The fissure represents a break down in reality.  Whatever the shape of the planet (if it even is a planet) the fissure is just a literal hole in space-time physics.

The possibilities for shape of the planet and what else lies on the planet are limited only by what Gehn wrote into Riven.  That's the way The Art works.  Any conceivable (or inconceivable) reality that would contain the details laid out in the descriptive book could work.  Riven could be inside a giant space ship, or a ring world.  It could even be a inside-out sphere world (which would explain the fissure quite well actually.)  Occam's razor would dictate that world is most likely round, and there are many land masses on which the creatures of Riven evolved.